# Sort array of objects by the length of a field using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array like below, and I need to sort the array by the string length of `name` field.
for an example,

```
[
  {
    "_id": 10,
    "name": "AAAAAA"
  },
  {
    "_id": 11,
    "name": "AA"
  },
  {
    "_id": 12,
    "name": "AAAA"
  },
  {
    "_id": 13,
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "_id": 14,
    "name": "AAAAAAAA"
  }
]
```

I need the array like this,

```
[
  {
    "_id": 13,
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "_id": 11,
    "name": "AA"
  },
  {
    "_id": 12,
    "name": "AAAA"
  },
  {
    "_id": 10,
    "name": "AAAAAA"
  },
  {
    "_id": 14,
    "name": "AAAAAAAA"
  }
]
```

can any one help me out with this. Thanks.

Comment: `array.sort((a, b) => a.name.length - b.name.length)`

Answer (score -1):

This can be accomplished with the [`_.orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) method:

```js
_.orderBy(data, [({ name }) => name.length, 'name'], ['desc']);
```

Here is a break-down:

I threw some "B"s into the mix to show the secondary sorting (after length is compared). Sorting the length alone is not unique enough.

```js
const data = [
  { "_id":  1, "name": "AAAAAA"   },
  { "_id":  2, "name": "AA"       },
  { "_id":  3, "name": "AAAA"     },
  { "_id":  4, "name": "A"        }, 
  { "_id":  5, "name": "AAAAAAAA" },
  { "_id":  6, "name": "BBBBBB"   },
  { "_id":  7, "name": "BB"       },
  { "_id":  8, "name": "BBBB"     },
  { "_id":  9, "name": "B"        }, 
  { "_id": 10, "name": "BBBBBBBB" }
];

const sorted = _.orderBy(
  data,                               // Data to be sorted
  [
    ({ name: { length } }) => length, // First, sort by length
    'name'                            // Them sort lexicographically
  ], [
    'desc',                           // Length (descending)
    'asc'                             // This is implied, and could be removed
  ]
);

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```